# What are the repercussions of letting Skinny Malone live?

Tags: fallout-4

An insight from Mama Murphy told me that when the time came I could talk my way out of the confrontation with Skinny Malone.

[image: rememberthequarry]

This allows us all to walk free with no deaths. During my first playthrough I killed everybody in the room.

What are the repercussions of letting Skinny Malone live?

Comment: Note: Even if you let him live, you still run a chance of his guys turning hostile on you if you stick around too long. I was overloaded when I had this encounter, and insisted on not dropping anything. So, I took too long getting away. I was far enough away from them though, that they never actually tracked me down. But I did see their radar blips turn red and heard them looking around. Didn't stay there long enough to see if I'd actually have to kill Malone or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had Piper as my companion and she liked my choice to "end peacefully" during the dialog options. I'm assuming this is the only benefit to letting him live. Guess I don't get to loot their corpses though, but I'm sure anything good they have would just get replaced soon.

Comment: He has an assault rifle (I think maybe "Heavy Assault Rifle"), but nothing very interesting that you can't find elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

There aren't, really.

Leaving Skinny alive has no impact on the story. Darla gets to live but that also has no impact on the story. If you spare Skinny you can find him in the wasteland later in the game south-west of the South Boston Military Checkpoint, where has some additional dialogue.

Comment: I haven't run into Skinny down there yet. Can you provide any more detail on where he's located?

Answer (score 1):

You can get Darla to turn on him by inciting violence. Any outcome that doesn't involve bloodshed causes Skinny and Darla break up.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow Skinny Malone to live after using the special dialog against him, you find him later out in the wild, and find out he's been kicked out by his crew. He vowes to become important again. I did his mission, but found out about finding him by YouTube.

I can tell you that the companion chick who speaks with an Irish accent & has red hair doesn't like if you use the special dialog on him. Piper probably on the other hand will like that you do. Using dialog is good.  Not using dialog & killing them is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The only repercussion is you cannot find him alive later.

Convince Darla to leave, (save before you try speech check in case you fail) but before you do place one Frag Mine at their feet, it will not activate. Convince her to leave, back up, as soon as she is clear, while there are still talking, lob 1 or 2 plasma grenades, makes for a one shot kill on all of them. If Darla is still close, she goes down to and Nick has to tell her parents she is dead. Easiest way, and quite a sight. (The Frag mine is set off by the plasma nade(s) but wont activate on them as long as they are green.)