# What did Mama Murphy just say?

Tags: fallout-4

I realised from the image in [What are the repercussions of letting Skinny Malone live?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243579/56379) that it would have been useful to understand what Mama Murphy was muttering about when she got hepped up on funny pills.

Is there a transcript of her visions somewhere? (I guess I can probably find YouTube videos of the conversations, but I'd prefer to read them!)

Comment: FWIW, you can turn on captions in-game for NPC dialog and other audio. I know this doesn't help you with Mama Murphy's mumbling in retrospect, but it's worth doing for future dialog. I always do this for Bethesda games--not only because the audio is sometimes unavoidably indistinct, but also because there's a _crap ton_ of dialog, and skimming subtitles lets me skip to the next step in a conversation way, way faster than waiting for someone to say the lines. (Sorry, voice actors.)

Comment: @FeralChimp, yeah, I usually prefer the subtitles off, because I prefer _not_ skimming through it and ignoring the voice actors, but when I give Mama Murphy a dose I'm going to turn them on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I performed a quick search for you; [this is from the Fallout Wikia page for The Sight](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sight). There are numerous 'sights' listed, I am sure one of them is the one you were looking for.

Also, remember, the game is still new so I reckon this to be **Spoilers**!

1. > > Diamond City holds answers, but they're locked tight. You ask them
   > >   what they know, but people's hearts are chained up with fear and
   > >   suspicion. But you find it. You find that heart that's gonna lead you
   > >   to your boy. Oh, it's... it's bright. So bright against the dark
   > >   alleys it walks. That's... that's what you need to do, kid. Follow the
   > >   signs to the bright heart.
   > >  **Used in Jewel of the Commonwealth**
2. > > You're looking for a man. He can help you, but he ain't gonna be the
   > >   man you expect. He's somewhere... deep... and dark. Surrounded by
   > >   folks with nothin' but cruel intentions. But there's... an echo...
   > >   Something in the past that can help you. When you meet the fat man,
   > >   and the angry woman, tell them to "remember the Quarry and Lilly June
   > >   on the rocks", and they'll let you and your friend pass.
   > >  **Used in Unlikely Valentine**
3. > > You're on the trail of the man who took your boy. I see a house.
   > >   Locked up tight. Chains put on by a smiling shark. But there's another
   > >   way. I can see it. A key. Lost and forgotten. Fallen down below.
   > >   Search the chairs beneath the house. They hold the secret.
   > >   **Used in Getting a Clue**
4. > > You walk into a house. The man who owns it has secrets. But he's no
   > >  fool. He hides everything in a closet with no doors. But I see him,
   > >  kid. He's sitting down. Brought out the red toolbox and the coffee.
   > >  Then he reaches beneath where he's working, and the closet opens.
   > > **Used in Getting a Clue**
5. > > I can only see that you're on the right path. If you had any doubts in
   > >  your mind, you shouldn't. The man you're after. He's the one. He wears
   > >  all the pain he's caused like a shield. Be strong, kid. The Sight's
   > >  getting... foggy... but your energy is glowing brighter than you know.
   > >  You can win this. He can't hurt you anymore.
   > >
   > > **Used in Reunions**
6. > > You're walking into a sea, but it's not water you're afraid of
   > >  drownin' in. It's something... invisible... but... radiant... It burns
   > >  everything in it, but... no... I can feel them. There's people.
   > >  Calling out to something. Chanting. They can show you the way...
   > >  but... they're so hard to read... Be careful around them, kid.
   > > **Used in The Glowing Sea**
7. > > I see you... the mighty hunter... only what you're hunting ain't an
   > >  animal, or a man. It's something different. Maybe something more than
   > >  human. But... what's this? I see a man in a white outfit. Standing
   > >  over your prey. And he says something... it's hard to make out... But
   > >  I'm tryin' kid... He says "Z2-47, initialize factory reset.
   > >  Authorization code Zeta-5-3-Kilo"... Then he falls... And he's
   > >  still...
   > >
   > > **Used in Hunter/Hunted**
8. > > I see you surrounded by outstretched hands. Everyone needs your help,
   > >  kid. Everyone wants you to see things their way... And whether you
   > >  want it or not... You're gonna have to decide which ways of life keep
   > >  going in the Commonwealth... and which end...
   > >
   > > **Used after Hunter/Hunted, before the Sole Survivor chooses a faction to side with.**
9. > > You're wearing a lab coat. You're standing with... men of science.
   > >   Visionaries. Brilliant but misunderstood. I see a land marked up, like
   > >   a great experiment. Each test a new beginning. Each sacrifice an
   > >   acceptable loss. You will not be loved, but you will save humanity.
   > >   However you choose to define it.
   > >  
   > >   **Refers to The Institute**
10. > > You're standing with... the people. Working together. United. I see a
    > >  land filled with hope again. Fear falls away as the brave step forward
    > >  to join the ranks. You're a hero. A symbol for a better world. Our
    > >  world.
    > >
    > >  **Refers to the Commonwealth Minutemen**
11. > > You're wearing a suit of steel and energy. You're standing with...
    > > your brothers. Your mission. Accomplished. I see a land secured,
    > > contained. Dangerous objects taken from those who don't understand.
    > > Those who can't be trusted. You are the uniform, and you wear it well.
    > > And your rank and chain of command protect you better than the
    > > thickest armor.
    > >
    > >  **Refers to the Brotherhood of Steel.**
12. > > You're wearing a mask. You're standing with... outcasts. The
    > >  underdogs. The lanterns in the dark. I see a world that will never
    > >  know your sacrifice. You have led the enslaved to freedom, but they
    > >  must still hide from those who don't understand. But you'll be there
    > >  for them. You'll see their humanity when no one else will. You'll be
    > >  their guardian in the shadows.
    > >
    > > **Refers to The Railroad.**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that page at nukapedia, only the Mama Murphy page ... should've looked harder.

Comment: So, what did he say? Pointing at a link doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Frank this is true, however there are 12 possibilities, leading to a rather lengthy answer. However you are correct, I shall place it in the body in case of link rot

Comment: Number 7 was the last I heard before *spoiler* she died.